# netbeans open file in same tab

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

when I click in on files, each file opens in a new tab. is there any preview mode like VSCode for NetBeans or any plugins. so if I change nothing to the file, same tab use to open the new file.

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible out of the box. Neither do I know a plugin which provides this functionality. But if you have some time you could write a plugin on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a plugin. this doesn't mock the VSCode behavior completely, but good enough.

- http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53723/one-click-open-sesame